# Check if Windows path is on locl disk or shared device

Tags: windows, share

I have a java application with many jars. I noticed that running the app from a share takes more time than running it from localdisk.

I would like to create a wrapper script that copies that jars to local disk only if the app was installed on a network path.

Is there a way to find out if a specific folder is on localdisk or network?

Answer (score 0):

you could use wmi for that : check drivetype of the [Win32_LogicalDisk class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx)
type 3 => local
type 4 => net drive

an example using powerhsell

```
 gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "deviceId='X:'" |select -expand drivetype
```

or

```
switch(gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filter "deviceId='X:'" |select -expand  drivetype){3{"local"}4{"network"}}
```